# convert vanilla javascript into react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to a intergrate a materialize.css Paralex plugin into my react hook functional component. how do i do that ? here is the code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
    var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems, options);
  });
```

please assist

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do with class components:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
  var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems, options);
}
```

Functional components:

```
useEffect(() => {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
  var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems, options);
}, [])
```

Hope this is what you needed :)

Comment: I got it, although where do i use the instances variable ?

Comment: you  could set it as a state variable so that you can use it anywhere in the component

Comment: Don't forget to `.destroy()` on the instance when the component unmounts!

Comment: I don't understand it very well. I'm very new to this. I understand the use effect part. but the variables part and the .destroy is a little confusing to me. would it be possible to explain this a little bit more clear,  thanks !!